# Python in ASP tag Windowws Server 2012

Tags: python-2.7, asp-classic, iis-7

**Using Windows Server 2012 and IIS 7 with Python 2.7 64 bit**

My cgi in python is working which is :

> print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"; print """
>            
>            
>            
>            
>             Environment<\br>""" for param in os.environ.keys():   print "**{}**: {}
> ".format(param,
>   os.environ[param]) print """
>            """

But when I am using python script inside an ASP page it is showing HTTP/1.1 500 server error

The code I am using is :

> <%@ LANGUAGE = Python%>
>
> <% import os for param in os.environ.keys():
>   Response.Write( "**{}**: {}
> ".format(param, os.environ[param]))
>   %>

Have Python with ASP in Server 2003  and Server 2008, but looking for guidance for Server 2012

Comment: Check your server logs to see the precise error message that is being generated. Post that along with your code. Also, you might want to put your question (i.e. the non-working code) in front of the working version.